# NGINX AddHandler equivalent?

Tags: nginx

Does anybody know what I would do in NGINX to accomplish this?

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .ws

I need to read .ws files as php

Answer (score 0):

if your conf looks like:

```
    location ~ \.php {
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;  
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9001;  
    }
```

then you would do this:

if your conf looks like:

```
    location ~ \.(php|ws) {
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;  
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9001;  
    }
```

not the change from php to (php|ws)